# Reducing boilerplate of binary layout handling in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Here is the code: https://github.com/EarlGray/haskell-snippets/blob/master/ext2hs/Ext2.hs

My problem is that it is quite painful to make large Haskell "records" and deserialize a binary layout with `Data.Binary.Get` manually like this:

```
instance Binary Superblock where
  get = binGetSuperblock

binGetSuperblock = do
  uint13  <- replicateM 13   getWord32le
  ushort6 <- replicateM 6    getWord16le
  uint4   <- replicateM 4    getWord32le
  ushort2 <- replicateM 2    getWord16le
  return Superblock {
    sInodesCount = uint13 !! 0,           sBlocksCount = uint13 !! 1,
    sReservedBlocksCount = uint13 !! 2,   sFreeBlocksCount = uint13 !! 3,
    sFreeInodesCount = uint13 !! 4,       sFirstDataBlock = uint13 !! 5,
    sLogBlockSize = uint13 !! 6,          sLogClusterSize = uint13 !! 7,
    sBlocksPerGroup = uint13 !! 8,        sClustersPerGroup = uint13 !! 9,
    sInodesPerGroup = uint13 !! 10,       sMountTime = uint13 !! 11,
    sWriteTime = uint13 !! 12,

    sMountsCount = ushort6 !! 0,    sMaxMountsCount = int (ushort6 !! 1),
    sMagic = ushort6 !! 2,          sState = ushort6 !! 3,
    sErrors = ushort6 !! 4,
    sLastCheckTime = uint4 !! 0,    sCheckInterval = uint4 !! 1,
    sCreatorOS = uint4 !! 2,        sRevLevel = (uint4 !! 3, ushort6 !! 5),

    sDefaultResUID = ushort2 !! 0,  sDefaultResGID = ushort2 !! 1,

    sDynRev = Nothing,
    sPrealloc = Nothing,
    sJournaling = Nothing
  }
```

(this is ext2fs superblock structure).

First of all, I would like to make binary layout as much declarative as possible, abstracting away those ugly sequences of `getWord32le` in `Get` monad with temporary fields. I want something like my python code, where [binary fields are unpacked to a map according to a `struct` format string](https://github.com/EarlGray/ext2py/blob/master/ext2.py)

The second thing I need is a more concise and more clear way for initializing a large Haskell record (creating a lot of temporary named values in the monad is pain).

One way I think of is to read binary fields into a heterogeneous map `forall a. BinaryField a => Map String a`, accessing each value by its name and pre-extracting most used ones to Haskell.
Perhaps Template Haskell and code generation from a declarative format may help, but I have no experience with TH yet.

I would be glad to hear any suggestions or hints about a more idiomatic way (are there any relevant tools?) or about the code in general (though it's just my learning code and it's very incomplete at the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to avoid those temporary values and (!!) operators, at the cost perhaps of some obscurity, would be something like the following:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>),(<*>),pure)

binGetSuperblock' = do 
    partiallyAppliedConstructor <- Superblock 
        <$> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord16le
        <*> (int <$> getWord16le)
        <*> getWord16le
        <*> getWord16le
    outOfPlace16 <- getWord16le
    partiallyAppliedConstructor 
        <$> getWord16le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> getWord32le
        <*> (OSEnum <$> getWord32le)
        <*> ((,) <$> getWord32le <*> pure outOfPlace16)
        <*> getWord16le
        <*> getWord16le
        <*> pure Nothing
        <*> pure Nothing
        <*> pure Nothing
```

Comment: Looks good. Do you have any suggestions how to fold this with a heterogeneous list of operations (assuming that there are no out-of-place fields)?

Comment: But now I see that the ordinary `foldl` won't work here: its type is `(a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a`; since application of `<*>` changes the type of partially constructed record, `(a0 -> b -> a1)` must be used.

Comment: @EarlGray: I take you mean to reduce repetition in those "getWord32le" by supplying a list of them and "filling them" in the record, in order. I suspect you would need Template Haskell for that.

Answer (score 2):

To add one more suggestion - building records can be simplified quite a bit by using the `RecordWildCards` extension, which automatically populates fields from visible names (see [GHC docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards)). Personally, I consider it borderline essential for dealing with large records. I would probably write this like follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
-- ...
binGetSuperblock = do
  [sInodesCount,         sBlocksCount,
   sReservedBlocksCount, sFreeBlocksCount,
   sFreeInodesCount,     sFirstDataBlock,
   sLogBlockSize,        sLogClusterSize,
   sBlocksPerGroup,      sClustersPerGroup,
   sInodesPerGroup,      sMountTime,
   sWriteTime]                            <- replicateM 13 getWord32le
  [sMountsCount,         sMaxMountsCount,
   sMagic,               sState,
   sErrors,              sRevLevel2]      <- replicateM 6  getWord16le
  [sLastCheckTime,       sCheckInterval,
   sCreatorOS,           sRevLevel1]      <- replicateM 4  getWord32le
  [sDefaultResUID,       sDefaultResGID]  <- replicateM 2  getWord16le
  return Superblock {
    sMaxMountsCount = int sMaxMountsCount,
    sRevLevel = (sRevLevel1, sRevLevel2),
    sDynRev = Nothing,
    sPrealloc = Nothing,
    sJournaling = Nothing,
    ..
    }
```